# Flatbuffers Verifier returns false without any assertion (FLATBUFFERS_DEBUG_VERIFICATION_FAILURE is defined)

Tags: flatbuffers

Sometimes the Verifier returns false without any Assertion in Verifier::Check() although. In my case VerifyAlignment() returned false.

Is there a reason, why VerifyAlignment returns false without calling Check?

```
  template<typename T> bool VerifyAlignment(size_t elem) const {
    return (elem & (sizeof(T) - 1)) == 0 || !check_alignment_;
  }
```

If I change VerifyAlignment this way, I get the assertion, which helps a lot:

```
  template<typename T> bool VerifyAlignment(size_t elem) const {
    return Check((elem & (sizeof(T) - 1)) == 0 || !check_alignment_);
  }
```

Comment: Yup, that may be a simple omission. Please file an issue or better yet, a PR, on GitHub.